# If $\mathrm{min}_{u\in U}||v-u||=||v-u_0||$, then $v-u_0\in U^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

**Problem**

Let $U$ be a subspace of an inner product space V (here V may not be finite dimensional). Fix $v\in V$. If there exists $u_0 \in U$ such that 
$\mathrm{min}_{u\in U}||v-u||=||v-u_0||$, then $v-u_0\in U^{\perp}$

**Attempt**

If $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u\in U$, then we see that the real function 
\begin{align*}
f(t)&=||v-u_0+ut||^2\\
&= ||v-u_0||^2+2t\mathrm{Re}(\langle v-u_0,u\rangle)+t^2||u||^2
\end{align*}
has a minimum at $t=0$. Thus $f'(0)=2\mathrm{Re}(\langle v-u_0,u\rangle)=0$. So $\mathrm{Re}(\langle v-u_0,u \rangle)=0$.

**Question**

I am stuck trying to show that $\mathrm{Im}(\langle v-u_0,u \rangle)=0$. I would be able to do this if I could show that $f(t)=\langle v-u_0+ut,v-u_0-ut \rangle$ has minimum at $t=0$.

Comment: That may be off, but why do you get real and imaginary parts in the first place? (the inner product is bilinear, not a sesquilinear form -- at least unless specified otherwise)

Comment: I am using the inner product as defined through the properties listed here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space ..., so in this case I believe it is sesquilinear

Comment: Try a *complex* $t$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

I will use A.G's comment.

First, $\mathrm{Re}(-iz)=\mathrm{Im}(z)$. This can be seen if we write $z=a+bi$: 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Re}(-i(a+bi)&=\mathrm{Re}(b-ai) \\
&=b\\
&=\mathrm{Im}(z).
\end{align*}

The case for real $t$ was proven in my attempt above. Now consider purely imaginary $t$, i.e $t=xi$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then the same calculation can be done:
\begin{align*}
\langle v-u_0+uxi, v-u_0+uxi \rangle &= ||v-u_0||^2+2t\mathrm{Re}(-i\langle v-u_0,u\rangle)+t^2||u||^2 \\
&= ||v-u_0||^2+2t\mathrm{Im}(\langle v-u_0,u\rangle)+t^2||u||^2. 
\end{align*}
Again, this function's derivative must vanish at $t=0$ so we find that $\mathrm{Im}(\langle v-u_0,u \rangle)=0$ for all $u \in U$.